# How to pass an array as part of extraParams?

Tags: extjs

I have code store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Test', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: CRM.Global.getApiUrlServer() + '/php/my_php_test.php',
        method: 'GET',
        extraParams: {
            ///
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            rootProperty: 'rows'
        },
    }
});
```

I want to pass an array to:

```
extraParams: {
         "test_array": [
                              "params1": "1",
                              "params2": "2",
                              "params3": ["3", "4"],
],
        },
```

When passing in the debugger, I see

`[Object Object]`

How do I pass it correctly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not quite well documented but the `extraParams` should be plain (i.e. not nested) object. This is sort of understandable as it is going to be passed on to the request object what is not prepared to del with complex data structures. So you need to serialize your complex stuff before you pass it on. I.e. try

```js
extraParams: {
         "test_array": JSON.stringify([
            "params1": "1",
            "params2": "2",
            "params3": ["3", "4"],
            ]),
        },
```